# Why is my UIView animation working differently?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, uikit, game-engine

I'm working on [a game engine](https://github.com/MosheBerman/MBTileParser), and I've run into a rather baffling behavior. I'm sure it's rather simple, but I'd like to figure it out before progressing.

I've subclassed `UIImageView` and added support for multiple animated sprites. I have controls working too, but I've been seeing a weird behavior. When my character walks up or left, the animation skips a frame, and appears to move faster. Moving right or down goes slower and displays the correct three frames.

I've gone through my whole call stack, and I can't figure it out. Here's what happens:

- The user taps on the virtual joypad.
- The game controller view controller dispatches a notification.
- The main player sprite picks up on the notification.
- The sprite asks the delegate if it's allowed to move where it wants to.
- The sprite moves in a given distance if it is indeed allowed to.

The sprite movement code looks like this:

```
//  Move in a direction
- (void)moveInDirection:(MBSpriteMovementDirection)direction distanceInTiles:(NSInteger)distanceInTiles withCompletion:(void (^)())completion{

CGRect oldFrame = [self frame];
CGSize tileDimensions = CGSizeZero;

tileDimensions = [[self movementDataSource] tileSizeInPoints];

if (tileDimensions.height == 0 && tileDimensions.width == 0) {

    NSLog(@"The tile dimensions for the movement method are zero. Did you forget to set a data source?\nI can't do anything with this steaming pile of variables. I'm outta here!");

    return;
}

CGPoint tileCoordinates = CGPointMake(oldFrame.origin.x/tileDimensions.width, oldFrame.origin.y/tileDimensions.height);

//  Calculate the new position
if (direction == MBSpriteMovementDirectionLeft || direction == MBSpriteMovementDirectionRight) {
    oldFrame.origin.x += (tileDimensions.width * distanceInTiles);
    tileCoordinates.x += distanceInTiles;
}else{
    oldFrame.origin.y += (tileDimensions.height * distanceInTiles);
    tileCoordinates.y += distanceInTiles;
}

if (![[self movementDelegate] sprite:self canMoveToCoordinates:tileCoordinates]) {
    [self resetMovementState];
    if(completion){
        completion();
    }
    return;
}

[self startAnimating];

[UIView animateWithDuration:distanceInTiles*[self movementTimeScaleFactor] delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{

    [self setFrame:oldFrame];
}
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     //  Perform whatever the callback warrants
                     if(completion){
                         completion();
                     }
                     [self resetMovementState];
                 }];
}
```

If the `MBSpriteMovement` direction (which is a typedef of `NSUInteger`) is up or left, `distanceInTiles` is a negative integer. The correct distance is calculated, but for some reason, the down and right seem slower. I'm certain it does skip a frame when moving up/left.

Any idea why?

(This is an open source project, and can be found [here, on GitHub](https://github.com/MosheBerman/MBTileParser).)

Comment: You are not showing the movement code.

Comment: Actually, I do. `[UIView animateWithDuration...` is that code. startMoving is actually akin to `UITableView beginUpdates`.

Comment: Sorry, that was off the screen...

Comment: Just download the zip for your full project. I can't find "MBDialogTree".

Comment: @S.P. Thanks for pointing it out. The files are there, but the xcodeproj wasn't updated. It should build now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make certain that the duration which is given to the `UIView` animation routine is non-negative. This is easily accomplished via the `fabs` function:

```
NSTimeInterval animationDuration = fabs(distanceInTiles*[self movementTimeScaleFactor]);

[UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                 animations:^{
                    //...
                 }];
```

Comment: After testing a bit, this is the problem!I actually prefer to put just the distanceInTiles in the `abs()` method, because it's the only negative value, but I suppose it could be safer to do it your way.